# Поиск элемента в массиве в определенном диапазоне в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, поиск

Мне нужно найти максимальный элемент и его индекс в определенном диапазоне массива. Т.е. к примеру дан массив a:

```
[
 [8, 2, 3]
 [4, 7, 1]
 [7, 2, 8]
]
```

Дан массив b:

```
[
 [7, 1]
 [2, 8]
]
```

Мне нужно в массиве b найти максимальный элемент и вывести индекс этого элемента из массива а. Вывод должен быть: a[2][2] = 8 - max

Comment: Используйте max, enumerate и списковые сокращения

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42463172/5741205 ;)